# Model with a foreign key field to a table name that is not in models file

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model_a = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA)

class ModelC(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    intermediate_ab = models.ForeignKey("database_intermediate", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The ManyToMany relation creates the intermediate table (`database_intermediate`) on the database.
Is it possible to refer to that intermediate table without creating the intermediate model, for use in the `ModelC`?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use the [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) attribute to explicitly define the intermediate model:

> Django will automatically generate a table to manage many-to-many relationships. However, if you want to manually specify the intermediary table, you can use the through option to specify the Django model that represents the intermediate table that you want to use.

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model_a = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA, through='MyIntermediate')

class MyIntermediate(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_b = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then you can refer to the intermediate model as follows:

```
class ModelC(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    intermediate_ab = models.ForeignKey(MyIntermediate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Note that after this change you wont't be able to use the Django admin widget. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models):

> When you specify an intermediary model using the through argument to a ManyToManyField, the admin will not display a widget by default. This is because each instance of that intermediary model requires more information than could be displayed in a single widget, and the layout required for multiple widgets will vary depending on the intermediate model.